# Security with JEE7

Tags: java, security, web

Someone already implemented security jee7? I'm reading the documentation of oracle but there just tells you how using the web.xml settings. Is there an example using a class accessing the database? something like in spring security?

tanks.

Comment: did you find anyting about this?